# Does .NET 4.0 have something similar to Container-Managed Transactions from Java?

Tags: java, c#-4.0, transactions, managed, container-managed

Sure, there is Transaction Scope, but is there also something like this:

http://java.sun.com/j2ee/tutorial/1_3-fcs/doc/Transaction3.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes there is.

Check [this](http://progtutorials.tripod.com/DotNetTransaction.htm) out

Also [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973865.aspx) looks more informative